# Annotate with Subquery "get" instead of "filter"

Tags: python, django

Why can i run an `annotate` with a `Subquery` featuring a `filter` query like this:

```
invoices = invoices.annotate(
    supplier_code = Subquery(Supplier.objects.filter(
        pk = OuterRef('supplier'),
        cep_country__name = OuterRef('cep_country'),
    ).values('code')[:1]),
)
```

But when i try to use a `get` query method gives me the error `ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.`

```
invoices = invoices.annotate(
    supplier_code = Subquery(Supplier.objects.get(
        pk = OuterRef('supplier'),
        cep_country__name = OuterRef('cep_country'),
    ).values('code')[:1]),
)

## OR

invoices = invoices.annotate(
    supplier_code = Subquery(Supplier.objects.get(
        pk = OuterRef('supplier'),
        cep_country__name = OuterRef('cep_country'),
    ).code),
)

## BOTH GIVE THE SAME ERROR
```

What's wrong here? Is it simply impossible to use a `get` query inside the `Subquery`? I can live with the `filter` option, but it would be more correct for me to use the `get` since i know for sure there's always one and only one match.

Comment: Since you are sure there will only be one match, doesn't that slice `[:1]` do what you want? `get` will not work because it is not lazy and directly makes a query to the database, furthermore get does not even limit anything unlike the slice so it is not even more efficient if that is what you are thinking.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat The slice works perfectly yes, this question was just out of curiosity because i thought the code would be more correct with the `get` (also was thinking maybe more efficient yes). Hmm i see, thanks for the answer. I had no idea that filter and get operated differently actually.. I've quickly read throught the docs now and i see that `filter` only returns a QuerySet while `get` instantly queries the DB. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuerySets are normally *lazy* since we can chain many methods on them, example: `.filter(...).order_by(...)`, etc. without any actual query being made to the database (Would be making too many unneeded queries otherwise).

But the `.get()` method does not return a queryset it returns an instance of the model and hence it cannot be lazy. So no you **cannot use `.get()`** in a subquery.

You already achieve what you want to do by performing that slice on the queryset `your_queryset.values('code')[:1]` what this does is it uses the `LIMIT` clause of SQL so that only one row will be returned. In fact this is better than using get anyway since it does not limit the number of results the database returns and if more than one result is returned it raises a `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception.

Comment: Yes exactly! Thanks for the answer, i've read your comment and the word "lazy" almost instatly sparked the answer inside my head. Like i said above i had no idea that filter and get operated differently.